# Send signals to child processes?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I'm using a Makefile to run [Packer](https://packer.io). It is extremely important that if I kill a task with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> that the signal is passed to the child processes.

As it stands, it appears that GNU Make simply aborts and does not send the TERM signal to the child process. Packer, upon receiving this signal, attempts to clean up resources, which is very important as it can be creating EC2 instances.

Answer (score 1):

I can't reproduce the behavior you're seeing:

```
$ echo 'all: ; @echo sleeping; sleep 600' | make -f-
sleeping
^C
make: *** [/tmp/GmjcnM8Y:1: all] Interrupt

$ ps -aef | grep sleep
```

After the C-c, the sleep program has also been killed.

So, you'll have to provide more details.

Comment: I think the issue is that the `packer` and `sleep` processes must be sent the signal and then disowned and sent to the background. Typically with Packer, if the TERM signal is sent, the process will emit more logs about how it's cleaning everything up. In Make, no more output is sent after sending TERM.

Comment: Sorry, but I didn't understand your comment.  Your question says that make doesn't forward the ^C (SIGTERM), but make does forward the ^C.  If there's more that needs to happen then you have to arrange for that on your own: make doesn't know anything about what the process it invoked actually does: it just starts a process and waits for it to complete.  If it gets a SIGTERM it will pass that along to the children.  Note that make uses process groups just like any other UNIX program: if the process you run changes to a different process group there's nothing make can do about that.